Как генерировать уникальный айди?
Пишу расширение для браузера и там будут данные пользователя, авторизации нет. Так вот, как при открытие расширения генерировать уникальный айди для дальнейших запросов на сервер? Насколько я понимаю если мы скажем сгенерируем айди формате XXX-XXX-XXX, то пользователь может поменять на другой формат его в LocalStorage и сервер посчитает его за верный. Как это тоже решить?

Если нет авторизации, то не важно поменян он или нет. Генерируй uuid4 чтоб перебор этих кодов был нецелесообразным.

Понял! Спасибо.

Если нет авторизации, то зачем вам уникальный ID? И уникальность должна быть на каком уровне? 1 ID - 1 сессия, 1 запрос, 1 пользователь?

Но если я даже буду генерировать его в uuid4, мне ведь по-любому на сервере нужно его сверять, т.к через localstorage я могу его поменять скажем на такое «123» и все

Swap, мне нужен уникальный id для получения данных пользователя. Как это делается на многих расширениях

uuid уже можно попытаться распарсить на сервере как uuid, если парсер выдаст ошибку, значит пошёл нафиг (но, разумеется, это всё равно не защитит от подмены одного uuid на другой uuid)

Ну и я об этом же. Получается, без авторизации никак это не сделать?

Ну, если вы хотите полностью заменить подмену, то вам придётся так или иначе изобретать какой-то способ проверки того, что этому значению можно доверять (а ещё думать о том, что делать, если пользователь решит просто стереть весь localStorage без всяких подмен)

Если он почистит localstorage, то ладно, решить можно, задача не такая и уж сложная, а вот это прям квест целый :)

Если вам нужно знать пользователя, то авторизация в той или иной мере нужна. Можно просто попробовать "логин" с "паролем" положить подальше, что бы только "умные" смогли его найти, например в indexDB

А что если использовать подход как сквозное шифрование? Ключ знают, а подменить по сути невозможно

чтоб сделать шифрование - надо знать ключь - знают ключ - могут зашифровать поновой

без авторизации ничего сложнее мд5 подписи не придумаешь

@eri закрытую часть ключа пусть знает только сервер

@andreymal тогда это уже авторизация.

@eri ну если сервер будет генерировать ключи всем подряд без предварительных проверок, то назвать такое авторизацией можно будет с трудом) Но это уже на совести автора, кому и при каких условиях он захочет генерировать ключи
